# Sending image name to html tag

Tags: html, angular

the main idea is showing picture according to selected id:

```
<div *ngIf="t">
  <h2>{{t.name}} details!</h2>
  <h3>{{t.description}}</h3>
  <img src="images/inside/1.jpg" class = "grid grid-pad">
</div>
instead of 1.jpg i would like to use t.filename? How can i do this?
```

Comment: use `<img [src]="t.filename" class="grid grid-pad">`